# Array element differerences using a for loop

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop, android-edittext

Really need some help, I have 3 editTexts and I need to grab the input from two of  them   in hh:mm:ss. Then find the difference using arrays and a for loop, and set as text  in third editText. Any input would be great!

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    end = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEnd);
    start = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etStart);
    diff = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDiff);
    calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCalc);
    clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bClear);

    calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int h1 = s[0];
            int m1 = s[1];
            int s1 = s[2];

            int h2 = e[0];
            int m2 = e[1];
            int s2 = e[2];

            String sGet2 = end.getText().toString(); // end to string
            String sGet1 = start.getText().toString(); // start to string

            String[] erA = sGet2.split(":"); // end string to end array
            String[] srA = sGet1.split(":"); // start string to string array

            for (int i = 0; i < srA.length; i++) {

                inted = Integer.parseInt(erA[i].trim());
                intst = Integer.parseInt(srA[i].trim());

                s[i] = intst;
                e[i] = inted;
            }


            if (s2 > s1) {m1--;s1 += 60;}

            if (m2 > m1) {h1--;m1 += 60;}

            int H, M, S;
            S = s1 - s2;
            M = m1 - m2;
            H = h1 = h2;
            diff.setText(H + ":" + M + ":" + S);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

*Also,
 if I run this With 1:2:3 as start time
 and 4:5:6 as end time. It spits out (6) only the last digit of the end time. If i set   end time to 3:4:5 it would display 5 in the editText.

Comment: Is it a typo/mistake or is it wanted that you have `H = h1 = h2;` and not `H = h1 - h2;` (equal sign instead of minus)? and what is the declaration of `s[]` and `e[]`?

Comment: no that was a mistake. int[] s; int[] e; * Now it just crashes when i hit Calc Button

Answer (score 0):

I think that there are 2 mistakes in your code:

first the assignements of

```
        int h1 = s[0];
        int m1 = s[1];
        int s1 = s[2];

        int h2 = e[0];
        int m2 = e[1];
        int s2 = e[2];
```

and then I think the computation at the end should rather be this:

```
if (s[2] > s[1]) {
     m[1]--; // What happens if m[1] is 0?
     s[1] += 60;
}

if (m[2] > m[1]) {
     h[1]--;
     m[1] += 60;
}

 S = s[1] - s[2];
 M = m[1] - m[2];
 H = h[1] - h[2];
```

You are mixing your variables. I think you should simply declare those arrays of int[] (s and e) in your method (instead of a member of your class) and get rid of s1, s2, m1, m2, h1 and h2.